# Replace all commas within a string with the first word of that string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there a way to capture the first word of a string and then replace all commas using the captured first word?

I have attempted a hundred ways without success. I must be missing something. Is there a simple way to set a variable with regex?

string example:
"somename",'2','3','4','11','22','33','44','etc...'

desired results:
"somename",'2'
"somename",'3'
"somename",'4'
"somename",'11'
"somename",'22'
"somename",'33'
"somename",'44'
"somename",'etc...'

I'm using notepad++ (v7.5.6) for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, does it absolutely *have* to be done within Notepad++, or can other solutions be suggested?

Comment: You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting problem... the best I could come up with inside notepad++ was this: Find `^([^,]+)(,.+)(,[^,]+)$`, replace with `\1\2\n\1\3`. This will replace

```
"somename",'2','3','4','11','22','33','44','etc...'
```

with

```
"somename",'2','3','4','11','22','33','44'
"somename",'etc...'
```

Continual pressing of `Replace` will eventually give you the desired output.

Hopefully someone else can do better...